# Creating new column from API lookup using groupby

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe of weather date that looks like this:

```
+----+------------+----------+-----------+
| ID | Station_ID | Latitude | Longitude |
+----+------------+----------+-----------+
|  0 | 6010400    |    52.93 |    -82.43 |
|  1 | 6010400    |    52.93 |    -82.43 |
|  2 | 6010400    |    52.93 |    -82.43 |
|  3 | 616I001    |    45.07 |    -77.88 |
|  4 | 616I001    |    45.07 |    -77.88 |
|  5 | 616I001    |    45.07 |    -77.88 |
+----+------------+----------+-----------+
```

I want to create a new column called `postal_code` using an API lookup based on the latitude and longitude values. I cannot perform a lookup for each row in the dataframe as that would be inefficient, since there are over 500,000 rows and only 186 unique `Station_IDs`. It's also unfeasible due to rate limiting on the API I need to use.

I believe I need to perform a groupby transform but can't quite figure out how to get it to work correctly.

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you try dropping duplicates, then calling the API? You can use `map` to map the results back.

Comment: Don't think that will work, I left out some unique weather data for each row in the example. I'm thinking I could just simply loop through each unique group and add the postal_code to each row that matches that group ID.

Edit: Just saw your edit. That might work as a better solution that what I considered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe, you can use groupby only for aggregations, which is not what you want.

First combine both 'Latitude' and 'Longitude'. It gives a new column with tuples.

```
df['coordinates'] = list(zip(df['Latitude'],df['Longitude']))
```

Then you can use this 'coordinates' column to create all unique values of (Latitude,Longitude) using `set` datatype, so it doesn't contain duplicates.

```
set(list(df['coordinates']))
```

Then fetch the postal_codes of these coordinates using API calls as you said and store them as a dict.
Then you can use this dict to populate postal codes for each row.

```
postal_code_dict = {'key':'value'} #sample dictionary
df['postal_code'] = df['coordinates'].apply(lambda x: postal_code_dict[x])
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Be careful, calling set on tuples of floats may not be a great idea because of floating point inaccuracies.